# Unsetting a variable in Velocity

Tags: java, templates, velocity

Is it possible to set a Velocity reference to 'null' or 'undefined'?

The [Velocity template language reference](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html) says

> `#set` - Establishes the value of a reference
>   Format:
>
> `# [ { ] set [ } ] ( $ref = [ ", ' ]arg[ ", ' ] )`
>
> Usage:
>
> `$ref` - The LHS of the assignment must be a variable reference or a property reference.
>
> `arg` - The RHS of the assignment, arg is parsed if enclosed in double quotes, and not
>   parsed if enclosed in single quotes. *If the RHS evaluates to null, it is not assigned
>   to the LHS.* (emphasis mine)

I cannot find an equivalent `#unset` macro.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read on...

> Depending on how Velocity is
>   configured, it is usually not possible
>   to remove an existing reference from
>   the context via this mechanism. (Note
>   that this can be permitted by changing
>   one of the Velocity configuration
>   properties)

In the VE default configuration has property

```
directive.set.null.allowed = false
```

> if true, having a right hand side of a
>   #set() statement with an invalid reference or null value will set the
>   left hand side to null. If false, the
>   left hand side will stay the same

Change it to `true` using `setProperty()` on `org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity` and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 24):

You can set the reference to false. As a non null reference is considered true, you can then test if the reference is set. This is useful in loops.

```
#foreach ($obj in $list)
#set ($x = false)
#set ($x = $obj.maybeNull())
#if ($x)
...
$x
#end
#end
```

Comment: Since velocity variables will keep the old value, if you try to assign a "null-value", I found this solution quite nice. At the end of the loop I just set the variable to false and when you cannot assign a value it's value will be false.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to get scoped variables, you can abuse the scope established by `#foreach`:

```
#foreach($localVar in [ 'theValue'])

#end

## localVar will be unset (or returned to previous value) again
```